Can I enter Japan with 2 different passports (in separate times)
I have dual citizenship, Passport A & B.
I've been using Passport A to enter Japan from all my previous travels, but currently I need to renew it and cannot use it during renewal time.
So does anyone know if I can enter Japan with Passport B?

Are you asking if the visa in A is valid for B? Or are you concerned about presence days count? What triggers the question?

I dont need VISA for both passports My concern is if they will deny my entry if they see I used a different pasport than last time. Since they do finger print & facial recognition at customs

It's fine as long as you use a single passport for each trip (i.e. always use the same passport for exit that you used for entry). Both travel documents are valid and there is no requirement to use the same for different visits.

It's fine: I am a dual national, have entered Japan with both my passports, and have never been asked about it or had any other problems.
As a rule of thumb, while some countries (like Japan) do not permit dual nationality for their own citizens, they don't care about the dual nationality of non-citizens.
